# Error trying to install guest operating system on virtual pc

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

I'm on Windows 7 and am trying to install another instance of Windows 7 into a virtual PC virtual machine.

The instructions say to put the Windows 7 install disc in the DVD drive and then startup the virtual machine.  The virtual machine is then to see the bootable media and start the installation process.

Here's what I get:

[image]

My machine info:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtual PC doesn't do 64 bit guests. [VPC Release Notes](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/4/c/44ccd131-67fb-4224-a96e-193be1765b43/relnotes.htm)

You can use VMWare Player , vmware workstation, Virtualbox, or either of the newer MS Virtualisation apps (APP-V, HyperV).

Vmware did have an ISO image (vt.iso) that you could mount in a Virtual machine, and it'd tell you if your virtualisation platform, and your host, supported 64bit and had the Intel virtualisation technology installed, but I can't find a link for it.

Hope that helps.

Nick

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to install the 64-bit version of Windows 7 into Virtual PC which isn't supported, even if the host machine is 64-bit.

I would recommend using [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) instead which can support 64-bit guests.

Answer (score 0):

Adam,

Microsoft does have an [official Windows 7 Support Forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/category/w7itpro/). It is supported by product specialists as well as engineers and support teams. You may want to also check the threads available there for additional assistance and feedback.

Jessica
Microsoft Windows Client Team